# Is it possible to make a background-position animation inside svg?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, background-image

I'm trying to make a gradient animation in the background of a  of a svg. Is this possible?

```css
.ani_a {
    background-color: #fff;
    animation: anibg01 10s infinite linear;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,#0d4ba0,#00adee,#00aba5,#37b34a,#8dc63f,#ccdb29,#ffdd15,#fff100,#f6921e,#f05a28,#ec1c24,#ff008b,#90278e,#652d90,#0d4ba0,#00adee);
    background-size: 1500% 100%;
}
@keyframes anibg01 {
    0% { background-position: 0% 0%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 100%; }
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <polygon class="ani_a"  points="35,70 70,70 105,0 70,0  "/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more - do you want a changing linear gradient just within that shape or actually behind the whole SVG? Does it have to be an SVG particularly (as opposed to a CSS clip path for example)?

Comment: `background-color` is not animatable.

Comment: @Azu background-color is animatable but they are not trying to animate a background-color they are trying to move a background-image.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I meant background-image.

Comment: @AHaworth i want to use it inside an svg element not the whole svg background

Comment: @Azu they aren't trying to animate a background-image they want to animate the background-position which is animatable.

Comment: So just to clarify, you want what appears as a black shape in the SVG to instead be a moving background - to have the same visual effect as the div background animation in my answer but it's a shape in the SVG? (I'm trying to make sure I understand what it is that has the background image).

Comment: Have you investigated SVG linearGradient and animation (rather than CSS)?

Comment: @AHaworth svg animation could work indeed. maybe i have to go that way. have to investigate that. yes the black shape (should) have the moving background image

Comment: yes i have it working! thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to animate the linear gradient (by moving it) within that shape you could take an alternative approach using CSS/HTML rather than SVG to define the shape.

This snippet takes the linear-gradient and makes it the background of a div. The div is clipped to give a shape using clip-path with a polygon and the background is animated to move vertically downwards with repetition.

```css
.ani_a {
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: anibg01 10s infinite linear;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #0d4ba0, #00adee, #00aba5, #37b34a, #8dc63f, #ccdb29, #ffdd15, #fff100, #f6921e, #f05a28, #ec1c24, #ff008b, #90278e, #652d90, #0d4ba0, #00adee);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 20vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  display: inline-block;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
}

@keyframes anibg01 {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 10vmin;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ani_a">div</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. yeah a div will work! but i need a solution for a element in a svg. I have a more complex svg but i stripped it down for the code snippet.